How should I be "thinking" of jazz chord progressions?
I understand how pop music can create chord progressions by using I ii iii IV V vi vii° as a reference (if we're doing a song in a major key). For example, the famous I V vi IV progression.
But what about Jazz? I was analyzing The Great Pumpkin Waltz and saw in the beginning it plays Cm7, Bm7#5, B♭m13, E♭7. I don't think this fits into the I ii iii IV V vi vii° toolbox?
How would the composer come up with a chord progression like this without using I ii iii IV V vi vii° as a reference (or maybe he is and I don't realize it)?
Or am I thinking about this the wrong way, and I should frame the process of creating a jazz chord progression differently?
Thanks in advance.

Also, take a look at Rick Beato's training courses. Since he's interviewed Andy Summers (who took jazz chords into the Police's rock songs!), I can't imagine he would have skimped on teaching this part of music theory. :-)

There is not one jazz style.
You have to understand the history of jazz and its various roots.
The jazz comes from the early forms of Blues, which implies a certain form of chord progression (I7 I7 IV7 I7 V7 I7).
The jazz comes also from all the musicals of the early 20th century built on the tonal classical system.
In the bebop area, you had also that particular attention to the ii V I.
Jazz composers took similar paths as the classical composers also: extend the tonal system to its furthest limits, even further than its late 19th century evolution. Even get rid of it, and think modal instead of tonal, …
I could also speak about the non-western influences: Africa, India, …
This is all to say that there is not one jazz. I would recommend watching Adam Neely’s video The Seven Levels of Jazz Harmony. Fun and instructive.

To understand your example, you have to know about cadences and all the various common chord substitutions techniques.
If you substitute the Cm7 with AbMaj7 (which is a typical “median” substitution (both chords are a 3rd away and have many notes in common Cm7: C, Eb, G, Bb, while AbMaj7 is Ab, C, Eb, G), you progression becomes AbMaj, Bm7#5, Bbm13, Eb7 which is a classical I ii V (if we omit the Bm7#5).
The Bm7#5 has no function: it is a voice-leading chord that brings from the Cm7 to Bbm7 by chromaticism:


The third chord is Bbm13 (or I would call it Bbm6), which also has a G note, so there is a long G note through all the chords.

The Bm7#5 is 'kind of' (though not exactly) a tritone substitution for F7. If you replace it with F7 (or some altered version of F7) you get a series of descending 5ths in the bass, which is probably the most common chord progression in jazz.

In a nutshell, jazz and music in general is not limited to the seven diatonic chords. In very general terms pop music is sometimes less sophisticated and many songs will fall within the seven diatonic chords, or even only 3 or 4 of them as shown in the famous progression you quoted. Jazz is more harmonically sophisticated (once again in general) than most rock, pop and R&B music so you will see many chords and progressions that go way beyond the seven diatonic chords although often some of those 7 chords are at the heart of jazz progressions.
An answer on this forum is not the place to give someone an education in jazz harmony because that information is way too broad to include here. There are many books or online resources that have that knowledge and you can find them with some investigation.
Some of the more common techniques that jazz uses to go beyond the simple triadic diatonic chords are:
The use of 6,7,9,11 and 13 chords
Modulating to other keys within a song
The use of secondary dominants
The use of ii-V’s in place of V chords
Modal interchange, especially using parallel minor diatonic chords in songs in major keys (for example, using a bIII, iv, bVI or bVII in a major key)
Chromatic passing chords
Substitute dominant chords
The use of modes
Chords that are completely non functional
The list goes on and on but this is a good starting point for understanding what makes jazz harmony so unique and sophisticated.
As for “Great Pumpkin Waltz” this is definitely way beyond the “toolbox” you mentioned. It is a combination of descending chromatic harmony mixed with 2-5’s and inversions. The second chord is really a G/B which is actually a V of Cm. What makes this segment of the progression work so well is the fact that the G melody note is a common tone of all four chords.


...create chord progressions by using I ii iii IV V vi vii°...

Another way to describe that is using the triads for a given key signature. When you limit chords to only those within a key signature, and not using any sharps or flats to alter pitches from the key signature, you call that diatonic harmony. The set of diatonic chords for a minor key is more complicated, but we can skip that for now.

...How would the composer come up with a chord progression like this without using I ii iii IV V vi vii° as a reference...

Just to provide the associate term, harmony that includes pitches outside of diatonic harmony is called chromatic.

Or am I thinking about this the wrong way, and I should frame the process of creating a jazz chord progression differently?

Well, if you are thinking that all harmony must be diatonic, that would be "wrong" in the sense there is no such requirement in music. Harmony can be diatonic, chromatic, both, or use a completely different system beside the major/minor key system. Chromatic - or non-diatonic - harmony is not something exclusive to jazz. I happens in pop, rock, classical, jazz, lots of different styles.
Some chromatic harmony is really just an extension of diatonic harmony where the music moves into different keys or changes between major/minor modes. Terms that describe that include secondary dominants and borrowed chords.
Another broad chromatic harmony category is altered chords. Examples in classical style include augmented sixth chords and Neapolitan chords. In jazz there are tritone substitutions and altered dominants.
Chromatic chords can be the result of chromatic passing tones. A classical example can be seen in the harmony throughout Chopin's E minor prelude. In jazz an example in C major could be C C#dim7 Dm.
Parallel motion, sometimes called planing, can introduce non-diatonic chords. For example, in C major, playing chords Ab Bb C.
The examples I have given are not meant to be an exhaustive list, but a sample for you to understand there a number of well known harmonic devices, or systems, that musicians use to go beyond simple diatonic harmony. You can think about those things when studying chord progressions in jazz or other styles.

I listened to the Great Pumpkin Waltz just now - the beginning annoyingly flits between C minor and E flat major, and later sections drift into G major (or return to the beginning's material) - but the ending reinforces E flat major more than C minor, so I think analyzing the beginning as being in E flat major is justified.
And in E flat major, your Cm7, Bm7#5, B♭m13, E♭7 chord progression is this:
vi7 ♭vi7#5 (really a passing chord) v13 I7
An alternate take is that the Bm7#5 chord is actually a Gadd2/B chord instead, which leads to this Roman numeral analysis:
vi7 Vadd2/vi v13 I7
Note that I have labelled the B♭m13 chord as v13 because it gives off a strong dominant-chord impression despite being a minor (extended) chord.
I therefore cannot eliminate the possibility that the composer was using I ii iii IV V vi vii° as a reference. The chords are functional enough here and later, and uses of the tonic (i.e. I), subdominant (i.e. iv or IV), and (secondary?) dominant are later blatant.

There seems to be the universal belief that chords ought to be diatonic. Just not true! Especially in jazz.
Yes, there may well be that tendency in a lot of pop stuff, but jazz will use all sorts of other harmonies, as portrayed in the other answers.
Often there will be 'theoretical' reasons - tts, V/V, and so on, but often, there won't be a simply explained reason theoretically. Unless one wants to get terribly involved but what's the point?
Just take each change on its own merit - if it happens to fit the 'must be diatonic rule', then sobeit, but one of the beauties of jazz is that it sometimes breaks the 'rules', which is why it's jazz! Basically, expect the unexpected (and unexplained!) and take things at their face value. Music theory is there to explain what has already happened - maybe one day, there'll be a revelation, and we'll be able to explain the vagaries of jazz changes. But, why bother...

I kind of think that you should frame the process of creating any chord progression differently. Let me explain.

I understand how pop music can create chord progressions by using I ii iii IV V vi vii° as a reference (if we're doing a song in a major key).

That's strange. Can you name me a popular song using the vii° chord? I'm asking because, in my experience, if there is a diminished chord, it's usually iii° instead.
(Admittedly my reference isn't pop music as a style, but popular music in a more general sense.)
From what I've observed, it's generally like this:
Staple chords include: I, V(7), IV, I7, vi, ii.
Common chords include: VIIb, III(7), iv, II(7), iii.
Unsurprising chords include: IIIb, IVmaj7, Imaj7, V(7)sus4, vii, VI(7).
There is some kind of regularity to it, but "it's the chords where every tone is diatonic to the scale - and none other" is not it. There's a correlation, sure. There even seems to be a mild tendency for active preference towards diatonic chords, but it isn't the main factor.
What works better is that if you describe the given chord's relationship to the tonic using "dominant", "subdominant", "relative minor" and occasionally "parallel minor" (for example: ii - subdominant of relative minor of the tonic), then the shorter the chain of relations, the more abundant the chord is likely to be. Roughly. And there's no hard binary cutoff but rather gradual thinning.
Chords that come after one another are generally fairly closely related to each other, too. Usually up to two steps of relation.
Anyway, this (tracking relations to tonic) is the way of thinking about it that I find more useful and aligned with reality than taking a whole scale and mechanically adding a third and fifth within that scale to each step.
I'm still talking about popular music. Jazz will complicate things as it often likes to throw in stuff that isn't related. Semitones up and down just because.
But this is the basic frame of how to think of chords in general, IMO.
